# Handling XML Parsing errors in T-SQL

Tags: xml, t-sql, sqlxml

I am trying to create a report that audits an incoming XML data feed.
We validate incoming transactions against the information in our system, only inserting data from the transactions if they match certain data points on a valid record.

My report looks through all the recent incoming transactions that failed this validation and then attempts to read out some of the data from each transaction so that we can manually inspect the issues and request our vendor to correct the information and resend.

Occasionally, we get some invalid xml. Sometimes it's truncated, sometimes it's missing a tag, etc.
My report works fine when the xml is valid, but the query errors out completely when it encounters a transaction with invalid xml.

I need to upgrade my code so that the entire query doesn't error out when it encounters invalid xml.
Ideally, it would handle this by pulling all columns as 'NULL' when an invalid xml is encountered or, better-yet, pulls in the good parts of the xml (the tags that are properly closed).

Typically I get: "XML parsing: line 9, character 0, unexpected end of input"

Here's a mockup of the current structure of my query (notice the second XML file is invalid/truncated):

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT, xmlcontent XML);
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES

(1, '
<Movie>
<MovieID>1234</MovieID>
<MovieName>Mission Impossible</MovieName>
<Character>
    <FirstName>Ethan</FirstName>
    <LastName>Hunt</LastName>
</Character>
</Movie>'),

(2,'
<Movie>
<MovieID>5678</MovieID>
<MovieName>Casino Royale</MovieName>
<Character>
    <FirstName>James</FirstName>
    <LastName>Bond</LastName>
')

SELECT
ID,
allnodes.value('(MovieID)[1]','nvarchar(100)') as MovieID,
allnodes.value('(MovieName)[1]','nvarchar(100)') as MovieName,
allnodes.value('(Character/FirstName)[1]','nvarchar(100)') as FirstName,
allnodes.value('(Character/LastName)[1]','nvarchar(100)') as LastName

FROM @mockup mockup
--Get all the transaction data:
CROSS APPLY mockup.xmlcontent.nodes('Movie') as xmldata(allnodes)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Error explanation**

The sample code from your question indeed returns the *"unexpected end of input"* error, but that error originates from the *insert*. The SQL Server engine validates if the input value is properly formatted XML data because of the `XML` data type in the table definition (table variable `@mockup`).

**Solution**

If you want to pull in all data first - valid *and* invalid XML's - then you will have to change the table column data type from `XML` to something like `nvarchar(1000)`.

Processing invalid XML's can then be attempted with the [`TRY_CONVERT()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql). This function will return `NULL` if the conversion fails. So no partial processing: this would require a much longer solution that manually parses the string type data and completes missing XML tags... SQL Server is not the prime candidate for such kinds of text parsing and manipulation.

```
create table mockup
(
  ID INT,
  xmlcontent nvarchar(1000) --- changed type
);

INSERT INTO mockup (ID, xmlcontent) VALUES
(1,
'<Movie>
  <MovieID>1234</MovieID>
  <MovieName>Mission Impossible</MovieName>
  <Character>
    <FirstName>Ethan</FirstName>
    <LastName>Hunt</LastName>
  </Character>
</Movie>'),
(2,
'<Movie>
  <MovieID>5678</MovieID>
  <MovieName>Casino Royale</MovieName>
  <Character>
    <FirstName>James</FirstName>
    <LastName>Bond</LastName>');

with cte as
(
  select m.id,
         try_convert(xml, m.xmlcontent) xmldata -- introduced TRY_CONVERT()
  from mockup m
)
select c.id,
       xmlmovie.node.value('(MovieID)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as MovieID,
       xmlmovie.node.value('(MovieName)[1]','nvarchar(100)') as MovieName,
       xmlmovie.node.value('(Character/FirstName)[1]','nvarchar(100)') as FirstName,
       xmlmovie.node.value('(Character/LastName)[1]','nvarchar(100)') as LastName
from cte c
outer apply c.xmldata.nodes('Movie') as xmlmovie(node); -- changed to OUTER apply to show NULL values
```

**Result**

```
id  MovieID  MovieName           FirstName  LastName
--  -------  ------------------  ---------  --------
1  1234      Mission Impossible  Ethan      Hunt
2  null      null                null       null
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6c4dd376e783bdda19490ad779c164bd) to see error reproduced on insert and working solution.

Comment: So it looks like this would work, except I just discovered the db I'm working with has a compatibility level of 100 (2012); 110 is the minimum level for TRY_CONVERT() and our dba has told me they won't upgrade the compatibility level because this db serves some legacy applications that might break if the compatibility it set higher. Any backup solutions?

Comment: [Compatibility level 100](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level) would be SQL Server 2008 (R2). You could try to program something with manual XSD validations through [XML Schema Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms176009(v=sql.90)) which still exists from SQL Server 2005 as show in [this post](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/xml-schema-validation-in-sql-server-1). Handling the XML parsing error might pose problems for a viable solution :-/